# Why does IList<>.Reverse() not work like List<>().Reverse

Tags: c#, list, interface, methods, ambiguity

I have problem with `List<T>.Reverse()` and `Reverse(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`.
Look to the code:

```
  // Part 1
  List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

  foreach (int x in list)
    Console.Write(x);

  Console.WriteLine();

  list.Reverse();

  foreach (int x in list)
    Console.Write(x);

  Console.WriteLine();
  list.Reverse();

  // Part2
  IList<int> ilist = list;

  foreach (int x in list)
    Console.Write(x);      

  Console.WriteLine();

  ilist.Reverse();

  foreach (int x in ilist)
    Console.Write(x);

  Console.WriteLine();

  ilist.Reverse();
```

My result:

```
123
321
123
123
```

because `Reverse()`-Part1 is `List<T>.Reverse()`, `Reverse()`-Part2 is `Reverse(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`
I want execute `List<int>.Reverse()` in Part2 for `IList<int>`. How I can do it?

Comment: [I agree with you that this is confusing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828917/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-the-net-api/2829051#2829051)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IList<int>` doesn't have a `Reverse` method, so it uses the extension method.  The only way to use `List<T>.Reverse` on your `IList<int>` reference is to cast or convert it to a `List<int>`.  Casting will only work if you're sure that it's really a `List<int>` in the first place:

```
IList<int> abstractList;
var concreteList = (List<int>)abstractList;
concreteList.Reverse();
```

Another option would be to *create* a `List<int>` from your `IList<int>` instance, rather than assuming it already is a `List<int>`:

```
IList<int> abstractList;
var concreteList = new List<int>(abstractList);
concreteList.Reverse();
```

The *reason* that the `Reverse` extension method doesn't actually affect the underlying list is because it operates on `IEnumerable<T>`, which isn't necessarily writeable (none of the `Enumerable` extension methods make changes to the original collection, they return a *new* collection).

To use this version of `Reverse`, just use the product of the `Reverse` call, rather than the original list:

```
IList<int> abstractList;
IEnumerable<int> reversedList = abstractList.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 4):

In the second example, you're using an extension method against `IEnumerable<T>`, and this is not mutating the original collection but rather producing a query that would result in a sequence of your original list in reverse order. That is to say, if you want to utilize the results of `ilist.Reverse()`, you would say

```
var reversedList = iList.Reverse(); 
// reversedList is IEnumerable<int>
// 'list' and 'ilist' are not changed

foreach (int item in reversedList)
    Console.Write(item);
```

Comment: short, yet concise answer to the issue at hand. Helped me out. Thanks +1